# can I use static layout (native UI) in react native's native android implementation?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am writing a react native application and I want to use some of the static layouts (for Android) I have from my old application.

I looked at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html and wrote a few classes (MyViewManager.java and MyView.java).

I want to be able to use the static layouts I have for MyView.java.

I went through the facebook's react native code on github.

I could not find an appropriate method like setContentView(R.layout.myview). I was wondering if anybody tried this and this will work.

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can try out something like

The layout inflater will inflate given xml file and put it as a child of this(second argument in inflate), which is MyLayoutView.

See the definition of inflate and change arguments as per customization required.

```
public class MyManyViewsManager extends ViewGroupManager<MyLayoutView> {

}

class MyLayoutView extends FrameLayout {

  init() {
        rootItem = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.xmlfilename, this, true);
  }

}
```